# I am confused about routing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-5

in routes.php,we write some route for the controller. such as:

```
Route::post('/account/create',array(
    'as' =>'account-create',
    'uses'=>'AccountController@postCreate'
));
```

I know that 'uses' is to search for the controller,then what 'as' is dealing with?

Answer (score 4):

`as` is used to create a [`named-route`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes) in laravel.

As [`the doc says`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes):

we can use them to refer to the route while generating URLs or redirects:

```
//generate URL
$url = URL::route('account-create');
//redirect to the route from another
$redirect = Redirect::route('account-create'); 

// with helpers
$url = route('account-create');
$redirect = redirect()->route('account-create');
```

Comment: thanks! it seems that using 'as' provides us an easy way to get access to the routes.And it will not show on the web address.

Comment: @tigerDisplayName : easy way to refer to your routes in the application code. Basically it serves purpose of an alias.

Answer (score 0):

`as` is for creating named routes and in fact it's very useful. In your application you can create urls or redirection using this named route `URL::route('account-create');` and `Redirect::route('account-create');` and it gives you huge bonus.

If you decide that you want to change your url, you just change it in your route and everything will be working without a problem because in other parts you used only route name.

So for example if you use named routes:

```
Route::post('/account/create',array(
    'as' =>'account-create',
    'uses'=>'AccountController@postCreate'
));
```

and in other parts `URL::route('account-create');` and `Redirect::route('account-create');` and now you decide you want to change url from `/account/create` to `newaccount` you need to change only in `routes.php` `/account/create` to `newaccount` and your whole application will work without a problem

On contrary, if you used urls in other part of your application, if you want to change this route url you would need to change urls in many parts of your application so you should use named routes because it can save you huge amount of time if you decide to change some urls in future.

For example if you don't use named-routes:

```
Route::post('/account/create',array(       
    'uses'=>'AccountController@postCreate'
));
```

and in other parts `URL::to('/account/create');` and `Redirect::to('/account/create');` and now you decide to change your url from `/account/create` to `newaccount` you will need to change it not only in `routes.php` file but in all files that use this url where you make any `URL::to('/account/create');` or `Redirect::to('/account/create');`